# show custom error message for md-error in angular material 2

Tags: angular, validation, typescript, angular-material

I'm trying to show a custom error message using the [**md-error**](https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview#error-messages) directive from angular material, so I wrote that method below:

**Typescript File**

```ts
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl, Validators} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'input-errors-example',
  templateUrl: 'input-errors-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['input-errors-example.css'],
})
export class InputErrorsExample {

  nicFormControl = new FormControl('', [
    Validators.required,
    validateNICInput ]);

}

// custom error checking 
function validateNICInput(c: FormControl) {

  let NIC_REGEX_OLD = /(^\d{9}[V|v|x|X]$)/; // Regular Expression 1
  let NIC_REGEX_NEW = /[0-9]{12}$/;         // Regular Expression 2

  var old_statement = NIC_REGEX_OLD.test(c.value);
  var new_statement = NIC_REGEX_NEW.test(c.value);

  return ( old_statement || new_statement) ? true : {
            validateInput: {
              valid: false
            }
        };
}
```

**HTML File**

```html
<form class="example-form">
  <md-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input mdInput placeholder="NIC" [formControl]="nicFormControl">
    <md-error *ngIf="nicFormControl.hasError('required')">
      NIC is <strong>required</strong>
    </md-error>
    <md-error *ngIf="validateNICInput">
      Please enter a valid NIC
    </md-error>
  </md-form-field>
</form>
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/IHJUu8ty0uJlbBWlk0Kp?p=preview)

In the above code snippet, I'm trying to show a custom error message which is specific to **invalid inputs** using `*ngIf="validateNICInput"`.

However, the above approach does not work if I input an invalid value. The underline of the input becomes red colored and does not show the error text `Please enter a valid NIC`.

Here are the other approaches I have tried but failed so far:

**Approach 2**

```html
<form class="example-form">
  <md-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input mdInput placeholder="NIC" [formControl]="nicFormControl">
    <md-error *ngIf="nicFormControl.hasError('required')">
      NIC is <strong>required</strong>
    </md-error>
    <md-error *ngIf="nicFormControl.validateNICInput">
      Please enter a valid NIC
    </md-error>
  </md-form-field>
</form>
```

**Approach 3**

```html
<form class="example-form">
  <md-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input mdInput placeholder="NIC" [formControl]="nicFormControl">
    <md-error *ngIf="nicFormControl.hasError('required')">
      NIC is <strong>required</strong>
    </md-error>
    <md-error *ngIf="nicFormControl.hasError(validateNICInput)">
      Please enter a valid NIC
    </md-error>
  </md-form-field>
</form>
```

But none of the other approaches above work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your validator return is wrong. Use this statement instead:

`Typescript`:

```ts
return ( old_statement || new_statement) ? true : { invalidNIC: true };
```

`HTML`:

```html
<md-error *ngIf="nicFormControl.hasError('invalidNIC')">
  Please enter a valid NIC
</md-error>
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/iZTuEEw4550sat6p1thL?p=preview)